# Moving every zero to the right side of a given array of integers

Tags: java

I am trying to move every zero to the right side of a given array of integers. But the while loop dose not work correctly and the output is same as input array. How can I fix it?
input : [5,4,0,3,2,0,1,7,0]
expected output: [5,4,7,3,2,1,0,0,0]

```
public class Examp167 {
    public static void exchange(int[] array){
        for (int j=0; j<array.length; j++){
            if (array[j]==0){
                while (array[j] != 0) {
                    for (int i=array.length-1; i!=j ; i--) {
                        int temp = array[j];
                        array[j] = array[i];
                        array[i] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.print(array[j]+ " ");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[] {5,4,0,3,2,0,1,7,0};
        exchange(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide example input with expected output and current output.  Currently you at least have a logic issue because you check `if (array [j] == 0)` then immediately check if `array[j] != 0`,these both could never be true at the same time.

Comment: You check if `array[j]` is 0, but if it is then your loop only runs while `array[j]` is NOT 0 so it never runs. `if (array[j] == 0) { while (array[j] != 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wouldn't mind the cost of creating a new array, or if you want to keep the original array unchanged, you can consider a new array of the same size as the original one, as the brand new array's values default to zero's, so you just need to put non-zero values at the beginning of the new array and no need to append zeros at the end.

```
private static int[] exchange(int[] a) {
    int[] someArray = new int[a.length];
    int count = 0;
    for (int num : a) {
        if (num != 0) {
            someArray[count] = num;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return someArray;
}

int[] a = new int[] { 5, 4, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1, 7, 0 };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(exchange(a)));
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't provide an exact code, but you should look up the dutch national flag problem and try to build up your solution from that. The gist of it is that, whenever you see a 0, swap it with the rightmost element and move the pointer `r--` if that makes sense and keep doing it until your left pointer `l` is `l < r`.

The pseudo code would be something like this

```
int l = 0; int r = array.size() - 1;
while(l < r) {
 if(array[l] == 0) swap(array[l], array[r--]);
 else l++;
}
```

It should work, but I haven't thought it through, it should give you an idea on a way to solve it at least.

Here is what it could look like in Java:

```
public class Test { 

    public static void exchange(int[] array){
        int l = 0; 
        int r = array.length;
        while (l < r) {
             if(array[l] == 0) {
                 r--;
                 int temp = array[l];
                 array[l] = array[r];
                 array[r] = temp;
             }
             else {
                 l++;
             }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[] {5,4,0,3,2,0,1,7,0};
        exchange(a);
    }
   }
```

**Output:**

> [5, 4, 7, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: I wrote your pseudocode in Java, mind if I add it to your answer?  I tested it and it worked as well.

Comment: By all means do!

Comment: Look over it and make any changes you want, I just whipped it up quickly.

Comment: The fact that this produces the same as the question's expected output, despite being an "unstable" sort, and the non-zero elements are in a different order to the input array, strongly implies this is the algorithm one is expected to write.

Answer (score 0):

The listed "expected output" does not quite reflect what the instructions say. If all you want is to move the zeros to the end, without modifying the order of other entries, then the expected output would be "5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0", not "5, 4, 7, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0". 
The following code for the exchange method leaves the order unmodified:

```
   public static void exchange(int[] array) {
      int l = 0;
      int r = array.length - 1;
      while (l < r) {
         if (array[l] == 0) {
            for (int i = l + 1; i <= r; i++) {
               array[i - 1] = array[i];
            }
            array[r--] = 0;
         }
         else l++; //
      }
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
   }
```

Comment: Won't it have a bug if you end up bringing a zero to the place you `l++` from? I think the `l++` should be in an else block not just always called.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the in-place, I was just practicing code and this just popped into my head, O(1) space solution for this problem!
The idea is very similar to the un-stable code, only difference being, instead of tracking the last place and randomly swapping, we tracking from the beginning and do it in a stable manner, by making sure we send non-zeroes to the beginning in a left to right traversal.

Pseudo code:

```
for(int lastNonZero = 0, cur = 0; cur < nums.size(); cur++) {
    if(nums[cur] != 0) {
        swap(nums[lastNonZero++], nums[cur]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package numberprograms;

public class ShiftAll0AtEndInArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int count = 0;
        int arr[] = new int[] {5,0,4,9,0};
        int tempArr[] = new int[arr.length];
        // shift all zero in right side ;
        for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i] != 0) {
                tempArr[count] = arr[i];
                count++;
            }
            
        }
        //now print array;
        for (int i = 0; i<tempArr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" "+ tempArr[i]);
        }
    }

}
```